# Leading dots in a table with multiple columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to put leading dots in this table.[image: Table]

So what I want to do is to put leading dots that connect the fourth column which is the Project column and the 5 column which is the Activity column. I originally tried to just use the "dotted" table border under the cell but it covers the entire bottom and I don't need it under the text.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: please past Your code to snippet

Answer (score 0):

Add `table-layout:fixed;` to the style of the table then in the `td` that has the subject (the field you want the dots) add `white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;` to the style. Then you can just put some huge span of dots and the overflow of the dots will be hidden.

Comment: Thinking of accessibility, would the dots be read by something like a screen reader or would they just be ignored?